# [Java]BufferedReader from socket with \r\n

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, msn

I'm trying to read text from a msn switchboard socket

```
public String readStream() {
    String temp = null;
    try {
        temp = buffReader.readLine();
        System.out.println("<<< " + temp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return temp;
}
// this method is called
public void print() {
  while (socket.isConnected()) {
      readStream(); 
  }
}
```

The output should be like this when a message is recieved on msn (according too http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/switchboard/example_session.php)

```
<<< MSG bob@passport.com Bob 143\r\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n
X-MMS-IM-Format: FN=Lucida%20Sans%20Unicode; EF=B; CO=ff0000; CS=0; PF=22\r\n
\r\n
Hello.
```

My output:

```
<<< MSG myemail@email.com MYNAME 128
<<< MIME-Version: 1.0
<<< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<<< X-MMS-IM-Format: FN=Arial; EF=; CO=000000; CS=0; PF=00; RL=0;
<<<
```

As you can see I'm not recieving the sended message until the person sends another message.

Output:

```
<<< MSG myemail@email.com MYNAME 128
<<< MIME-Version: 1.0
<<< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<<< X-MMS-IM-Format: FN=Arial; EF=; CO=000000; CS=0; PF=00; RL=0;
<<< 
<<< helloMSG myemail@email.com MYNAME 127
<<< MIME-Version: 1.0
<<< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<<< X-MMS-IM-Format: FN=Arial; EF=; CO=000000; CS=0; PF=00; RL=0;
<<<
```

So how can this be solved so I can read the whole message?

Comment: no need to put [Java] into question subject, we have tags. And, btw, welcome to SO.

Comment: Have try with Scanner.class (Java 1.5 or >) more complete?

Comment: isConnected() is not the correct test. readLine() returns null at EOS: that is the terminating condition. Socket.isConnected() will return true forever. It returns the state of the socket, not of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the fact that the stream does not have a line break after the Hello.  Thus readLine is not detecting the end of the line until the the one that comes at the end of the first line of the next message.  You need to rely on the length of the message to read a predefined number of bytes in order to get the whole message.  Check this site out for some hints: http://www.hypothetic.org/docs/msn/resources/faq.php#howtoparse

EDIT: Logic to be implemented quoted from the above site THE MOST Relevant part is near the end:

Whenever new data from the server arrives over the socket, append it to a string that will be used as a "cache". Each time you receive data, call the cache parser function as well.

The cache parser function will examine the cache variable and look for a newline.

If one is not found, the function will return without doing anything.

If one is found, it will read everything from the beginning of the cache up to the newline and put it into a new variable. It will then remove the command up to (and including) the newline from the beginning of the cache.

The cache parser will look at the first three bytes of the command.

If the command is recognized as a regular command, it will call the handler for that command and loop back to see if there are more commands in the cache.

**THIS IS THE MOST RELEVANT PART**

If the command is recognized as a payload command, it will look at the specified length of the payload, and compare that to the length of the cache.

If it appears that the entire payload is in the cache, the cache parser will take out the beginning of the cache up to the specified length and store it into a payload variable. It will then call the appropriate handler for the payload function and loop back to see if there are more commands in the cache.

If the length of the cache is smaller than the specified length of the payload, then the cache parser will add the command back into the beginning of the cache and return.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this http://pastebin.com/E5SwXeBf but that didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: You need to implement the logic they gave you in the post.  Your code has the length hard coded to 127, it should read it from the MSG command. This link has the MSG command format, you should parse that to get the length of the buffer to read. Also your code does not ignore the messages that have "regular commands" as opposed to payload ones. I have included the relevant part of the post that details the logic to implement in my answer